# My variable is a char but it's telling me to convert it to char from string

Tags: c#, string, char

I've been learning C#, but after some angry Googling I still can't figure out what's going on here. I wanted to code a simple command-line program, but one of my variables is somehow not working correctly and I don't understand why. Here is the part of the code relating to the error:

```
            Console.Write("What operation? (Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide)");
            char Operator = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            if (Operator = "A")
               {
                   Answer = (Num1 + Num2);
               }
            else if (Operator = "S")
               {
                   Answer = (Num1 - Num2);
               }
            else if (Operator = "M")
               {
                   Answer = (Num1 * Num2);
               }
            else if (Operator = "D")
               {
                   Answer = (Num1 / Num2);
               }
            else
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Invalid operator");
               }
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + Answer);
```

VS just tells me that I can't implicitly convert from string to char, but the Operator variable has always been a char. I converted the ReadLine string for the variable, as the input would only be one character.

Comment: char literals are enclosed by single quotation marks, like 'A', not by double like "A".
Also, the "equals" operator is `==`, not `=`.

Comment: FYI If the user types more than one character before hitting enter `Convert.ToChar` is going to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your tests should be `if (Operator == 'A')` so you are comparing to a char rather than a string.

Also, if your input is invalid, Answer will be unassigned at the last line.

Comment: Do add to it: "A" is a STRING with A as the only character. 'A' is a CHAR. The literals (constants) int the if are all strings becvause the OP Did not bother to learn all the literal types in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes in C# mean that you are creating ***string literal***, you should use single quotes to specify that it is **char**. You can read more about chars and strings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netcore-3.1)

```
 Console.Write("What operation? (Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide)");
            char Operator = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            if (Operator == 'A')
            { 
            }
            else if (Operator == 'S')
            { 
            }
            else if (Operator == 'M')
            { 
            }
            else if (Operator == 'D')
            { 
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid operator");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

if operator compares the value with "==" (Comparision Operator).

Please try this code:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int Num1=6, Num2 =2, Answer =0;
        Console.Write("What operation? (Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide)");
            char Operator = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            if (Operator == 'A')
               {
                   Answer = (Num1 + Num2);
               }
            else if (Operator == 'S')
               {
                   Answer = (Num1 - Num2);
               }
            else if (Operator == 'M')
               {
                   Answer = (Num1 * Num2);
               }
            else if (Operator == 'D')
               {
                   Answer = (Num1 / Num2);
               }
            else
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Invalid operator");
               }
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + Answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char Operator = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
```

this will work only you enter 1 character like A, D, S, M . When your inputs will be like Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide you have to take first letter of them. For that you can use

```
char Operator = Console.ReadLine().toString()[0];
```

since every string variable is a char array you can take first index of it.

Comment: You don't need the `ToString()` since `Console.ReadLine` returns a `string`.  Also this doesn't really answer the question since the OP will still end up attempting to assign a `string` to a `char` variable in the `if` statements.